# Change password_hash to bcrypt

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, passwords, laravel-5.6

I took an old project and started to develop it again with Laravel but I am struggling with the usuers already registered on the database.

I believe they encrypted the passwords with the

> password_hash(' ', PASSWORD_DEFAULT) method

but I think Laravel uses the

> Bcrypt()

So I can't log in using those credentials. Is there any way I can change the encryption?

I don't want to ask the users to change the password or anything

Comment: You did read http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php, right?

Comment: Btw, it's hashed and not encrypted. Two different animals altogether ;-)

Comment: Does that help me change the old hashed passwords to bcrypt? I didn't thing it would work. Only to create new ones.

Comment: You can only create new ones, the hash is uncrackable. To convert to new ones takes a bit of work.

Comment: That's the thing. I would like to convert the old hashed passwords to the bcrypt one, withtout asking the user to change it himself.

Answer (score 3):

Reading [the very fine manual reveals](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) `PASSWORD_BCRYPT` method:

```
password_hash("thepassword", PASSWORD_BCRYPT);
```

If they have an existing password you can use `password_verify()` to confirm the password, no matter how it was hashed.

---

You can convert the user's to new password hashes, but only when they login. You will need to add another column to hold the new password, then when they login, check for an existing password (verify if possible) and a blank one in the new column. If the new column is not blank, compare to that with `password_verify()`. If it is blank, hash the new password with the method shown.

Ultimately everyone will get their hashing methid changed as they log in, but it will take some work on your part to get the code in shape enough top perform the conversion safely and securely.

Comment: In that case I would use it on the login and compare the password the user enters with the hashed one in the database. Right?

Comment: Right. If you want to change the method and convert the older passwords, the road is much longer.

Comment: I edited to reflect the method for creating the new hashes.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses bcrypt hashes, the same hashes used by password_hash with either PASSWORD_BCRYPT or PASSWORD_DEFAULT algorithms.

Therefore, the hashes are already compatible with Laravel.  This can be verified pretty easily using tinker:

```
> $hash = password_hash('test', PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
"$2y$10$OpnZSN0EbAzMCvywTAWyWOqOme6/3N/xe.nrpcUO6mhLumMxL6DYm"
> Hash::check('test', $hash);
true
```

Laravel also allows you to easily plug in your own implementation of the Hasher interface by binding to the ioc container.