# Hashing passwords in laravel

Tags: laravel, encryption, hash

I am migrating an existing app to laravel 6, the app is complete and I am just needing to migrate old users.

In the existing app passwords were stored using

```
password_hash($password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Since laravel uses bcrypt can i migrate these passwords or will i need to force users to reset password?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I believe you should be able to migrate these passwords as-is: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53016990/4257068

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Laravel uses bcrypt helper. So, you should use this:**

```
$hashedpass = bcrypt('yourpassword');
output of which you can save to your database table's password field.
```

**Another option that Laravel offers:**

The Laravel Hash facade provides secure Bcrypt hashing for storing user passwords.

First include the Facade in your file:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
and use Make Method to generate password.

$hashedpass = Hash::make($request->newPassword);
and when you want to match the Hashed string you can use the below code:

Hash::check($request->newPasswordAtLogin, $hashedPassword)
```

You can learn more with the Laravel document link below for Hashing:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/hashing

Answer (score 0):

In my laravel app, i tried using bcrypt to encrypt password, but had issues decrypting or comparing. hence, i used Hash available in

Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;

Since you hashed it you can use:  Hash::check() to compare the password.

it takes two parameter : Hash::check(password, hashed_password);

try and see.